# Downloading list of files from Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

In my app I want to show a list of videos.For that I am looking for a storage option as backend and I found Firebase Storage which can store videos and images.

But how can i fetch list of videos/images from this storage?Basically I want that my app should contain list of thumbnails and on clicking on thumbnail respective video will play.

By what I understand through doc is that firebase storage allows download file by creating a reference to that file.That means to download list of files I need to create reference to all those files.And Firebase storage doesn't support json.

So how will I link between video thumbnails and their respective video? If Firebase Storage is not ideal for my requirement then what should I use?And i have no knowledge of PHP so i can't create the backend myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to store your links in a Firebase database. Every time you add an image/video to Firebase Storage, add also a reference to that file in the Firebase database.

Your database should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    --- videos
          |
          --- videoId1
          |      |
          |      --- videoLink: "https://..."
          |      |
          |      --- thumbnailLink: "https://..."
          |
          --- videoId2
          |      |
          |      --- videoLink: "https://..."
          |      |
          |      --- thumbnailLink: "https://..."
          |
          --- videoId3
                 |
                 --- videoLink: "https://..."
                 |
                 --- thumbnailLink: "https://..."
```

Comment: But the videos I am uploading from device as files and are not available as URL.How to store video file in database?

Comment: You get the url of the file while uploading it to Firebase Storage. Once you get the link, you can store it in your database. It's a JSON database and can be queried very simply.

Comment: thanks..How should my database look if i want to add  video link,video thumbnail and video name?Firebase db doesn't support array