# How to get the url from promise in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-storage

```
 const ref = this.storage.ref('/angfire2store/'+uniqueKey);
    const task = ref.put(this.selectedFile);
   task.then((snapshot) => {
     console.log(snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL());
    })
```

This code returns a promise and I want to extract the image url from it. I am using firebase storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const ref = this.storage.ref('/angfire2store/' + uniqueKey);
const task = ref.put(this.selectedFile);
task.then((snapshot) => {
    return snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
})
.then((url) => {
  console.log(url);
  return url;
})
.catch(console.log);
```

Comment: How do I get the list of all the images? I want to display these images. As soon as I refresh the page, the list gets empty!

Comment: @Nikita You need to [keep track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48851073/downloading-list-of-files-from-firebase-storage) of the files as you upload them.  Add another `.then` block that writes to the Firebase FireStore or Realtime database information about the file URL.  Then use something like [RxFire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxfire) to produce an async list of images.

Comment: Here is an [AngularFirebase](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/introduction-to-rxfire-rxjs-for-firebase/) tutorial on using RxFire.  I think the example uses Stencil, but there are other tutorials on the site for using RXJS in Angular.